# What components should I use for a high-power (5kW) projection system, which projects a binary pattern onto a 250x250mm surface(pixel size of 0.05mm)!

Tags: optics, lasers

For a machine, which I am currently designing I need a very high-power projection system. I have been trying to make a rough concept over the last few days, but have gotten stuck, because I got a bit lost on the internet. Mainly because I found to much different information about what I can expect from different optical components.
The requirements I am targeting:

- 250x250mm projection area
- Resolution: A projected pixel should be around 0.05mm --> 5000x5000 Pixel (on the projected surface)
- Power: 5kW (15% on time, 0.25s bursts)(Power of the laser)
- Pattern: I want to project all kinds of binary patterns with unified illumination.

My concept so far:

1. Laser (haven’t settled for a wavelength yet, somewhere in the infrared spectrum, like Fiberlaser or so, I want to heat the projection surface and infrared light is absorbed the best)
2. Passive DOE for beam shaping creates a flat top square (square with unified illumination)
3. Concave lens (to spread the laser beam of a larger area)
4. Pattern Generator (My problem)
5. Projection surface

2&3 can possible be switched or even combined.

4: I didn’t find any optical components which can create a pattern and deal with the high power as well. Components I have considered include DMD, active DOE’s, Liquid Crystals on Silicon. In some articles it is written that these components can deal with up to a few kilowatts, but I haven’t found any component that can deal with more than a few hundred watts.
Aren’t there any components that can handle so much power? Did I miss a Technologie?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: 5kW of what?  ... it that the total power usage of the device?

Comment: Welcome. // What‘s the purpose or application? Why using invisible infrared?

Comment: @jsotola I meant the the power of the laser I want to use.

Comment: @MS-SPO I want to heat surface I am projection on. In my research I have found that infrared is absorbed better by the materials I want to heat.

Comment: @Engineer_2005x: Thanks. Can you please EDIT your qeustion and post this and the laser power info there, too? Would be easier for readers. // I suggest to look at the high-energy community, where lasers are used to start nuclear fusion etc. Even president Reagans star-wars initiative may be worth a try for components you're after.

Comment: is this for a 3D printer?

Comment: @MS-SPO Thanks for suggestion.